# Sum Column in Created View using MySQL

Tags: mysql, sum, aggregate-functions

I'm trying to create a view which displays all late fees the month to date but also sums the late fees at the bottom of the result.

This is the script I've written to display details of the late fees:

```
select g.game_id, g.game_name, 
       if(datediff(r.return_date, r.due_date) > 0, 
           datediff(r.return_date, r.due_date) * g.overdue_charge_per_day,
           0) as Total_Overdue_Charges_MTD     
from rental as r
left join game as g
on r.game_id = g.game_id
where month(r.return_date)=month(now())
```

This gives me the following output:

```
game_id game_name Total_Overdue_Charges_MTD    
  6       GTA V              4.00
  7       Tony Hawk          15.00
```

I've named this view as overduepaymentMTD.

What I'd like the output to look like is

```
game_id game_name Total_Overdue_Charges_MTD Total    
  6       GTA V              4.00            19.00
  7       Tony Hawk          15.00
```

Is there a way of including the sum of total_overdue_charges_MTD in the view itself?

Comment: mind formatting you question to make it more redable.

Comment: Sorry, thought it would do it automatically

Comment: I did it. You need to indent code four spaces.

Comment: Ok thanks Jones, didn't know how to do it!

Comment: In the SQL world sums are often computed by `SUM(something) ... GROUP BY anotherthing`.   That generates one row per each distinct value of `anotherthing` showing the sums. Could you explain what you want to do more clearly? Maybe you could [edit] your question to show us how the sum would appear in this example.

Comment: In my output, I need to sum the Total_overdue_charges_MTD column - so it displays the charges for the month to date but also sums the charges underneath (if this is possible?) I've edited  my question to show this

Answer (score 0):

you can insert to a view easily. it has same syntax as insert into table. use the following query will help you to do what you want

```
insert into overduepaymentMTD(game_name,Total_Overdue_Charges_MTD)
select "Total" as game_name,sum( if(datediff(r.return_date, r.due_date) > 0, datediff(r.return_date, r.due_date) * g.overdue_charge_per_day, 0))as Total_Overdue_Charges_MTD from rental as r left join game as g on r.game_id = g.game_id where month(r.return_date)=month(now())
```

to work this query game_id,game_name must have default value or you have to add values to them in the query.

Comment: So what you've given me is just a total column of the overdue fees, this I can do, but I need to detail the individual late fees and sum them in the same view

Comment: after you created the view overduepaymentMTD using the query you have written in your question, you have to execute my query. after that if you select * from view, detail of individual late fees will be there and last row will be total | sum_value

Comment: When I try to insert your query I get the error 'the target table overduepaymentMTD of the insert is not insertable-into

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to figure out how to do this, instead I created a view of overdue charges for the current month and then summed the column overdue charges.